# Content loading in JSF page layouts

Tags: jsf, web

I am developing an application in JSF. My page has been divided into 3 layouts. Menu bar will be displayed at left side and content will be shown at center of the page. I want menu bar in all pages throughout the application. Now i have achieved it using templates. But its reloading the entire page while clicking the menu items.

Is there any other option to display the content in the content area without reloading the entire page?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I have faced similar issues in my application. You have to use `<f:ajax>` within your menu item and render only the div you want refresh.

e.g.

```
<f:ajax render="idOfDivToRefresh" />
```

Comment: Arun thanks for your reply. I am creating menu at managed bean since menu items will change based on user profile. So i coudln't use tour solution. Is there any other option to reload only part of  a layout

Comment: Yes you can reload only part of a layout using the  <f:ajax render="idOfDivToRefresh" />. If you want to reload more than two part of layout then in render properties put comma separated ID. Use actionlistner in menu item to call backing function and reload the menu and content there.